# Cascading dropdowns in Angular Kendo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-kendo

I have a few cascading dropdowns which work fine when the kendo-drop-down-list directive is not used. As soon as I convert the dropdowns to kendo dropdowns the cascading stops working.
[Here is the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BRsieG8IT1EFrfAeZnxt?p=preview)

On a side note if you remove the kendo-drop-down-list directive from the dropdowns the cascading works.Thanks a ton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i figured out a way to do it. I basically wrote a change event and updated the dataSource of the second dropdown. The plunkr has been updated.

[Plukr Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BRsieG8IT1EFrfAeZnxt?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this example using datasource:

[Plunker here!](http://plnkr.co/edit/tjRAKXIkItfJ8JFJydrh?p=preview)

Comment: my dataSource is a little different and my objects are nested.I figured out a way to do it.Thanks a ton